# When you cut off the excess wire from MIG torch, do you turn off the welder first?

Tags: welding

Just for safety concern, is it a good practice to turn off the welder first before cutting the wire?

Comment: Always good practice to turn off when not welding/working on it.  But you can cut the wire with it not off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open-circuit voltage on an arc welder (MIG, stick, or other) is typically 80 volts or even lower. Either your leather gloves or the PVC-dipped handles of the cutter alone provides plenty of protection for voltages in that range, and insulated handles held in a gloved hand is even better.

Beyond the safety concern there could also be a small concern about damage to the cutter. You've probably noticed that if you pull and release the torch trigger and then touch the wire to the work there's a small spark. If somehow your cutters were grounded and a spark were to occur when the wire contacted the cutter, the spark could slightly damage the cutting edge.

My typical practice is to touch the welding wire against the work or the ground clamp before trimming the wire. This removes any charge that might have been in the MIG's output capacitors so I know there won't be any sparking.

It may be interesting to note that operators do not routinely turn off a stick welding machine before changing the electrode. The electrode holder is live the whole time; the operator is protected from shock only by her gloves and possibly by the flux coating on the outside of the electrode. A MIG machine usually does turn off the electricity to the torch when the trigger is released, so one might argue that in terms of electric shock, the MIG is inherently safer than the stick method.

Comment: Interesting last paragraph. I've been welding for several decades, and always changed sticks bare-handed, never having even a tiny tingle. Never touch my work with body parts either.

Comment: Don't you get protected by your shoes as well?

Comment: Regarding MIG torch, I presume it's safe to lay it on a welding table given the trigger is released?

Comment: @JamesLin Yes - the MIG torches I've used were all plastic anyway except for the nozzle. I believe the nozzle is supposed to be electrically insulated from the weld wire too, but perhaps that might vary among brands or styles. Even if it's not insulated, when the current to the weld wire is cut off, it would be cut off from the nozzle too.

Comment: Hi Greg another question, about stick welding, what happens if I accidentally drop the holder to the ground, will it create short-circuit? Likewise I assume I cannot put the live electrode holder on the welding table?

Comment: @JamesLin  Welding is basically making a short circuit, but the path needs to be very well connected(clean metal at ground clamp and at weld point).  Dirt is bad at conducting electricity.  Changing/cutting electrodes/wires is done away from ground clamp(don't clamp a finger then try changing).  Welding table with ground clamp is not good place.

Answer (score 2):

Since you'll be using cutters with insulated handles, there's no point. Even if you didn't, and were sitting on the work, without pulling the trigger, there's nothing happening anyway.